# Checking if PowerPoint placeholder is empty

Tags: python, python-pptx

I'm using the [`python-pptx`](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) library maintained by `scanny`. I have manually inserted [placeholders](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/placeholders-using.html#insert-content-into-a-placeholder) in the Powerpoint template (in the layout, not in the slide).

I am looking for a way to check if a placeholder is already in use. I want to be sure that a picture placeholder does not contain any elements before inserting an image into it.

How do I express the `"placeholder is not in use`" part of the following code snippet?

```py
for placeHolder in slide.placholders:
    if placeHolder.name == "myplaceholder" and "placeholder is not in use":
        image = placeHolder.insert_picture("myimage.jpg")
```